# IE fails on 100% height in nested CSS tables

Tags: html, css-tables

I have a page layout with several nested CSS tables. All of these tables have 100% height. As long as the browser window is high enough to fit all without scrolling, all the tables have the correct height. When the browser window get too small to fit the height of the content, the innermost table collapses in height and the 100% height is ignored. This happened with IE 11. All other browsers manage to get it right, including Edge.

I have tried different CSS rules, especially adding explcit 100% height to all parent elements. I also tried adding all divs for the table rows.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/181d0qu1/1/

To reproduce the error, use IE and reduce window height until the vertical scrollbar appears.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    background: #9A9A9A;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#spacer {
    height: 400px; 
    background-color: silver;
}
#right > div {
    background-color: rgb(194, 206, 214);
}
#top > div {
    height: auto;
    background: #EECCCC;
}
#bottom > div {
    height: 1px;
    background: #EECCEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <div id="intermediate" class="table">
            <div class="cell">
                <div id="spacer">spacer</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div id="right" class="table">
                    <div id="top" class="row">
                        <div class="cell">top</div>
                    </div> 
                    <div id="bottom" class="row">
                        <div class="cell">bottom</div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot showing the behaviour in IE (correct when window is high enough to the left, resized window on the right):

[image]

Is there a way to make IE keep the innermost table at 100% height without leaving away any of the nested elements?

Comment: First of all, if you use table layout, use the according `table`/`tr`/`td` tags and do not abuse divs for something they are not supposed to do. Second, it looks like you are using this for layout purposes, in which case I would avoid using a table in the first place...

Comment: @Christoph The elements are not to contain tabular data, so I won't be using `table` / `tr` / `td`. The reason why I need to use the CSS table layout is making things stick to the bottom of columns while keeping everything expandable.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or two for us mac users?

Comment: @cullub As you requested, I added an Image with screenshots.

Comment: You are completely right, that tables are for tabular data, so why do you use a table layout? That was legit 15 years ago, but nowadays we have flex-box (or for non-production use grid-layout), so there is absolutely no need for such convoluted markup.

Comment: @Christoph flex-box support in IE is far buggier than CSS tables, so that is not an alternative for me. And please don't let this degenerate to the old discussion when to use tables / CSS tables / flex-box, as I am not looking for alternatives to CSS tables, but for a solution using CSS tables.

Comment: Obviously table layout is buggy in IE as well. So rather than asking how to fix your current markup, you should say, what exactly you want to achieve in the first place (and which browsers you have to support) and than perhaps we can come up with a more elegant solution.